# Project reactor - react to timeout happened downstream

Tags: spring, timeout, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Project Reactor has a variety of [timeout()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#timeout-java.time.Duration-) operators.

The very basic implementation raises `TimeoutException` in case no item arrives within the given `Duration`. The exception is propagated **downstream** , and to **upstream** it sends **cancel** signal.

Basically my question is: is it possible to somehow react (and do something) specifically to **timeout** that happened **downstream**, not just to **cancelation** that sent after timeout happened?

My question is based on the requirements of my real business case and also I'm wondering if there is a **straight** solution.

I'll simplify my code for better understanding what I want to achieve.

Let's say I have the following reactive pipeline:

```
Flux.fromIterable(List.of(firstClient, secondClient))
        .concatMap(Client::callApi)         // making API calls sequentially
        .collectList()                      // collecting results of API calls for further processing
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(3000))   // the entire process should not take more than duration specified
        .subscribe();
```

I have multiple clients for making API calls. The business requirement is to call them sequantilly, so I call them with `concatMap()`. Then I should collect all the results and **the entire process should not take more than some `Duration`**

The **Client** interface:

```
interface Client {
    Mono<Result> callApi();
}
```

And the implementations:

```
Client firstClient = () ->
        Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(2000L)) // simulating delay of first api call
                .map(__ -> new Result())

                // !!! Pseudo-operator just to demonstrate what I want to achieve
                .doOnTimeoutDownstream(() ->
                        log.info("First API call canceled due to downstream timeout!")
                );

Client secondClient = () ->
        Mono.delay(Duration.ofMillis(1500L)) // simulating delay of second api call
                .map(__ -> new Result())

                // !!! Pseudo-operator just to demonstrate what I want to achieve
                .doOnTimeoutDownstream(() ->
                        log.info("Second API call canceled due to downstream timeout!")
                );
```

So, if I have not received and collected all the results during the amount of time specified, I need to know **which** API call was actually canceled due to downstream timeout and have some callback for this "event".

I know I could put `doOnCancel()` callback to every client call (instead of pseudo-operator I demonstrated) and it would work, but this callback reacts to **cancelation**, which may happen due to **any error**.

Of course, with proper exception handling (`onErrorResume()`, for example) it would work as I expect, however, I'm interesting if there is some straight way to somehow react specifically to timeout in this case.

Comment: There is no contextual information provided to cancelled publishers, so I think it is not possible to determine what was the cause of the cancellation. Maybe this could be an API evolution proposal.